# Capturing Java Application Traffic with Fiddler

Tags: java, http, fiddler, capture

I've seen this question asked many times before, along with solutions, however they don't work for me.

I have a Java Jar file application that I want to run (a Runescape private server) and see what happens when you do something in the game (you claim a vote, which I assume makes some sort of a HTTP request to servers) and I want to see the response.

I tried this: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurejavaapp

However it didn't work.

Any help?

Comment: I am not sure about fiddler, I used it only for browser related debugging, but you can use WireShark to accomplish this.

Comment: @korhner Does wireshark show it in similar fashion to Fiddler? Also, does it have a Auto-responder type thing?

Comment: You can use wireshark to inspect network packets. Or you can use curl with a valid url and inspect the response.

Comment: Actually WireShark is far more powerful althrough it may be a little more difficult to use. Yes, it has along with many more features, you should check it out.

Comment: @korhner Okay so I downloaded Wireshark, and I can see it captures plenty of requests, however, it is hard to see which request belongs to my Java application. How can I see what the actual address is or if the request belongs to the application?

Comment: If you'd like, you can simply save the traffic from WireShark and then File > Import it in Fiddler. But are you sure that the application in question really makes a HTTP request rather than some other protocol?

Comment: @EricLaw Yeah it turns out it is some other type of protocol...